# WebDriverException on Travis-CI with Django and Selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium, travis-ci

Am getting an error in travis when running my `tox` tests after adding some `selenium` testing.  I attempted to follow the Travis docs [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-xvfb-to-Run-Tests-That-Require-GUI-(e.g.-a-Web-browser)).  However, I am getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect.
```

Below is my `.travis.yml` file.  Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?  Here is an [example of the test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998166/with-py-test-database-is-not-reset-after-liveservertestcase) I am running (from another question).

#### .travis.yml

```
language: python
python: 3.5
sudo: false
env:
    - TOX_ENV=py34-django18
    # many more environments follow
install:
    - pip install tox coveralls
script:
    - tox -e $TOX_ENV
after_success: coveralls
before_install:
    - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
    - "/sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /tmp/custom_xvfb_99.pid --make-pidfile --background --exec /usr/bin/Xvfb -- :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16"
```

### What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe this can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039530/unable-to-call-firefox-from-selenium-in-python-on-aws-machine

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just [passed](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#confval-passenv=SPACE-SEPARATED-GLOBNAMES) the `DISPLAY` environment in tox config to the test environment.

```
[testenv]
passenv = 
       DISPLAY
```